# How can I acquire a server session from a Lotus Domino OSGI servlet

Tags: servlets, osgi, xpages, lotus-domino

From a Domino OSGi Servlet I can acquire a user session using:

```
ContextInfo.getUserSession()
```

However, as part of the execution of the servlet I need to access a database to retrieve configuration settings. This database is only accessible to Admins and the server so I need, ideally, a signer or server session as well.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a server session with `NotesFactory.createSession()`.

The class must be imported by `import lotus.domino.NotesFactory;`

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution

Answer (score 1):

There are unsupported methods available in the lotus.domino code that can do this, which are used in `org.openntf.domino.session.NativeSession` (https://stash.openntf.org/projects/ODA/repos/dominoapi/browse/domino/core/src/main/java/org/openntf/domino/session/NativeSessionFactory.java#14 and https://stash.openntf.org/projects/ODA/repos/dominoapi/browse/domino/core/src/main/java/org/openntf/domino/session/LotusSessionFactory.java#63).

If you want that and more, [OpenNTF Domino API Starter Servlet](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API%20Starter%20Servlet/releases/8CBDB1CA595C4C5B852581A6005A82EA) uses ODA to provide a starter OSGi servlet that brings all the benefits of ODA plus examples of JSON handling from IBM packages and an optional HTTP Service. There is an introductory video on [NotesIn9](http://www.notesin9.com/2017/05/31/notesin9-206-rest-servlets/).

Comment: I've gone with the simpler answer below but there is a lot to like about ODA. I'd like to see an example of this working with a servlet that extends HttpServlet

Comment: That's what the Starter Servlet does to load and terminate the ODA Factory, see https://stash.openntf.org/projects/ODA/repos/starter-servlet/browse/parent/plugin/src/org/openntf/domino/demoServlet/ODADataServlet.java